# Поиск по spreadsheets

Tags: java, google-spreadsheet

Подключаюсь к google таблицам с помощью Java. Авторизация и чтение из них проходит нормально. Как организовать поиск по всем листам документа? Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Подключаюсь так:

```
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
        "Google Sheets API Java Quickstart";

/** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart");

/** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

/** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

/** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
 *
 * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
 * at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart
 */
private static final List<String> SCOPES =
        Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);

static {
    try {
        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

/**
 * Creates an authorized Credential object.
 * @return an authorized Credential object.
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in =
            SheetsQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                    .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                    .setAccessType("offline")
                    .build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    System.out.println(
            "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
    return credential;
}

/**
 * Build and return an authorized Sheets API client service.
 * @return an authorized Sheets API client service
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static Sheets getSheetsService() throws IOException {
    Credential credential = authorize();
    return new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.

    Sheets service = getSheetsService();

    String spreadsheetId = "1FOssRO2Swfua7Cc2-h78udmTbPgQJLm2voLu1s5XO5o";
    String range = "Лист1!A2:E";


    ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
            .get(spreadsheetId, range)
            .execute();
    List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();

    if (values == null || values.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("No data found.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Name, Major");
        for (List row : values) {
            // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
            System.out.printf("%s, %s\n", row.get(0), row.get(4));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, а как именно Вы подключаетесь к таблицам? Через API или по линке тащите? Дайте пример кода, чтобы было от чего плясать.

Comment: подключаюсь через API. Код прилагается.